# WCF Medium Trust Environment Which bindings to use

Tags: wcf

A question in 70-513 exam asked which 2 bindings should you use for a medium trust environment.

1. netTcpBinding
2. basicHttpBinding

Or

1. netTcpBinding
2. wsHttpBinding

Does anyone know what the correct answer  is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the answer is neither according to this [MSDN article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412171%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) If this is accurate, I would guess that something in the security or session implementation of the netTcpBinding might require full trust. Don't have the time to try but I'll add it to my list to try in WCF.

Answer (score 3):

The `BasicHttpBinding` and `WebHttpBinding` are fully supported in a partial trust environment. The `WSHttpBinding` is supported for `Transport` security mode only.

Bindings that use transports other than HTTP, such as the `NetTcpBinding`, the `NetNamedPipeBinding`, or the `NetMsmqBinding`, are not supported when running in a partial trust environment.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412186.aspx for more details.